# Accessing nested controls in custom validator

Tags: asp.net

How do I access asp.net controls that are nested multiple levels in a page from a custom validator?

Specifically, I am generating dropdownlists that are inside a placeholder, which is inside a repeater, which is inside of another repeater, which is inside of another placeholder.

I need to access the selected values of all of the drop down boxes to compare to one another.

My current solution is to loop through all of the controls inside each control, until I get down deep enough to access the dropdownlist's:

```
    For Each g As Control In sender.Parent.Controls
        If g.GetType().ToString.Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater") Then
            For Each k As Control In g.Controls
                If k.GetType().ToString.Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem") Then
                    For Each l As Control In k.Controls
                        If l.GetType().ToString.Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater") Then
                            For Each p As Control In l.Controls
                                If p.GetType().ToString.Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItem") Then
                                    For Each n As Control In p.Controls
                                        If n.GetType().ToString.Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder") Then
                                            For Each c As Control In n.Controls
                                                If c.GetType().ToString.Equals("System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList") Then

                                                'Add the dropdownlist to an array so that I can use it after all drop down lists have been added for validation.
```

This seems like an entire waste of resources. Is there a better way to access these controls from the custom validator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use `$` to concatenate container names to access a nested control; something like this:

```
ControlToValidate="panel1$usercontrol1$otherusercontrol$textbox1"
```

This does result in an internal `FindControl()` call to be performed by the validator which is somewhat expensive so you should use this approach sparingly.

In general, it's not a very good idea to access deeply nested controls inside other containers. You should treat these controls as private members of a page / control and not access them this way. Only use the above approach if you *really, really must*.

**Edit**: this may not be the perfect solution but I'd do it this way. Create a new DropDownListX control (derives from DropDownList) that grabs the page and checks if the page implements a new custom interface that you create. This interface can be used to register a control with the page and then your validator can go through this list and validate each registered control. Something like:

```
interface IValidationProvider
{
    void RegisterForValidation ( Control oCtrl );
}
```

Your page should implement this interface. Then in your new DropDownListX control:

```
protected override void OnLoad ( EventArgs e )
{
    IValidationProvider oPage = Page as IValidationProvider;

    if ( oPage != null )
        oPage.RegisterForValidation ( this );
}
```

Then in the page, when validation happens, you can go through the list of controls in the validation list and validate them one by one. Your custom validator won't have a single `ControlToValidate` control name but that seems appropriate for you, since you have 1 validator that validates multiple controls inside nested repeaters.

This solution gives you the ability to completely skip your current deep loop - if you have a control that needs validation, it'll register itself, otherwise the list in the page will be empty and nothing needs to be checked. This also avoids doing string comparisons for control names since controls don't need to be searched - they register themselves when they need to.

Comment: I don't know the id of the controls, as they are generated in the aspx file through multiple repeaters.

Comment: @KevinWasie Ah, it'll be a lot harder then. Do you have user controls inside the repeaters or do you simply place the controls directly inside the item templates?

Comment: Directly inside the item templates

Comment: I updated the answer - see if this approach would work for you. I did this kind of setup in the past and it worked well and it was a _lot_ faster than using recursive loops to search for controls. When you have a lot of incoming requests, that makes a big difference.

Comment: Wow that is cool. I can think of multiple instances where this framework will be beneficial. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinWasie I'm glad that it's useful to you. All the best.

Comment: How can I access this list in javascript for clientside validation also? I have tried creating a comma separated string of the client id of each dropdownlistX, and then registerarraydeclartion of the string in page_load, but at that point the dropdownlistx list is not populated yet, so how can I pass this list to javascript?

Comment: @KevinWasie You can try maintaining a string that contains a comma-separated list of all `ClientID`-s from the controls that you need to register. So as each dropdown registers itself, you can - in the page - also grab their `ClientID` property. You can then parse this string on the client side in JavaScript and use the client ID-s to access the various input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the control recursively?

```
private Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id) 
{ 
    if (root.ID == id)
    { 
        return root; 
    } 

    foreach (Control c in root.Controls) 
    { 
        Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id); 
        if (t != null) 
        { 
            return t; 
        } 
    } 

    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Still going to be a drain on the system. @xxbbcc method will be scalable for the traffic. thanks.